# Convert ColdFusion encrypt() to PHP openssl_encrypt()

Tags: php, encryption, coldfusion

I am hitting a wall right now; I am trying to convert the following [ColdFusion encrypt()](https://cfdocs.org/encrypt) code to PHP using [PHP's openssl_encrypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) method (PHP 7)

```
<cfset key = ToBase64(BinaryDecode("24a5d2b96b9aee2fb515c94fb36da508", "Hex"))>
<cfset encryptedString = Encrypt("Encrypting this string in CF and hopefully PHP too.", key, "AES", "Hex")>
```

Here is my attempt in PHP:
(I have updated my code. Thank you @Ageax for your feedback!)

However the results are still different.

```
$key = base64_encode(hex2bin("24a5d2b96b9aee2fb515c94fb36da508"));
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt(
    "Encrypting this string in CF and hopefully PHP too.",
    'AES-128-ECB',
    $key
);
echo '<p><strong>AES-128-ECB encryption</strong>: '.bin2hex(base64_decode($encrypted)).'</p>';
```

**Result in ColdFusion** (Thanks to @Ageax):

```
Key: JKXSuWua7i+1FclPs22lCA==
Encryption: 1CCA4C862D3D2DC85637AF2F0E532145DEFC135F1268D5DFA991C77ED624BA0228E557BAEB06D96925B4A2968ACF55AC1312F28BCC42CB89EADE6BB76BD698F5
```

**Result in PHP**:

```
Key: JKXSuWua7i+1FclPs22lCA==
Encryption: 4e487f1f9ff3ecaa82b5672803d9baecf5907c10bd91dbfdaf630927250c195f7e5a1d3e129da161b01a0a307ed73acf672d39614a91a53f6e1adcd1db6d1632
```

Any feedback would be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: We can't help you with your PHP code if you don't post it...

Comment: Hi @LukeJoshuaPark, I have just added the PHP code. Thanks!

Comment: @AHi - What's the result from PHP? One issue I spot is that the CF code is doing AES & ECB (because there's no "iv"), but the PHP code seems to be doing AES & CBC (has an "iv").  To make it easier to share results, here's a starter example of your CF code https://trycf.com/gist/e017802f111202ed19d8d4cf4e3b19c9/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: @Ageax Thanks for the feedback! I have updated my code, with the results for each language. It's still displaying different results, I feel I am really close but missing an important implementation detail. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I solved it!!! My mistake was to encode the key in base 64 (base64_encode), you just remove that and you are all set! Yay! :)

**WRONG:**

```
$key = base64_encode(hex2bin("24a5d2b96b9aee2fb515c94fb36da508"));
```

**CORRECT:**

```
$key = hex2bin("24a5d2b96b9aee2fb515c94fb36da508");
```

Thank you everyone for your feedback!

Comment: Thanks for posting the resolution.  One thing, the latest code uses ECB, which isn't recommended. Much better to use CBC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_(ECB)

Comment: Sure thing @Ageax! And yes, agreed! Thanks for all your help!